# How to get Orders using Customer Token?

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, rest-api, token

I want to access orders using customer token in rest API of Magento. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you please share what you tried?

Comment: I want to access orders using customer token using api.Same as /V1/orders api give response.